# Want to unselect all mat-radio-button in mat-radio-group after an independently event occurrs?

Tags: angular, angular-material

OK it will not let me include any code because I can't satisfy the formatting, I don't think it really necessary. I start out with a mat-radio-group with no mat-radio-button selected. The user is required to make a selection from the group. Independently of the Group of Radio Buttons an Event will happen when a Form on the page is submitted. On this event I would like to set all of the Radio Buttons back to the initial state of being unselected.

I can get the selected Radio Button by its ID but I don't see the "checked" attribute to remove. I don't see anything at the Radio Group level to unselect it, so I am lost how to do it. Right now I am just refreshing the whole page which seems like overkill.

Comment: Are you using [(ngModel)] (in this case only change the value of the variable)? Are you using Reactive Forms (in this case you only give value to the FormControl)?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: I tried to put the snippet of code for the mat-radio-group but it would not let me submit the question because I was not able to formatted correctly. It is not using  [(ngModel)] it is just being built form a JSON object.

Comment: Would you please try to provide unformatted code at least? Maybe we can edit to format it properly, because it's hard to understand your issue properly.
Quick Tip: add an initial note letting know you're not able to format it so no one will downvote due that. ;)

Comment: <mat-radio-group  id="matRadioGroup" required class="example-radio-group" >
        <ng-container *ngFor="let process of processList;">
          <mat-radio-button  class="example-radio-button" aria-labelledby="example-radio-group-label" *ngIf="process.processName != '';" [value]="process.name"  style="font-size:16px;"
                (change)="selectedProcess = process; loadComponent(process.processName, process.subName, processSpecifics.value);" >
                    {{process.name}}
          </mat-radio-button>
        </ng-container>
      </mat-radio-group>

Comment: It is just basically using an Array of Objects.

Comment: Thanks for any answers provided I will look into them. Since I did not write the application and don't want to make big changes I will just stick with refreshing the page to get it back to initial state.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using `mat-radio-group` correctly, then it must be binded to via `ngModel` to a property. Upon your independent event taking place, you can set the `ngModel` binded property to `null` or `''`.

Here's a simple example of the scenario you mentioned.

component.ts:

```
export class RadioNgModelExample {
  favoriteSeason: string;
  seasons: string[] = ['Winter', 'Spring', 'Summer', 'Autumn'];

  onSubmit() {
    this.favoriteSeason = '';
  }
}
```

component.html:

```
<label id="example-radio-group-label">Pick your favorite season</label>
<mat-radio-group
  aria-labelledby="example-radio-group-label"
  class="example-radio-group"
  [(ngModel)]="favoriteSeason">
  <mat-radio-button class="example-radio-button" *ngFor="let season of seasons" [value]="season">
    {{season}}
  </mat-radio-button>
</mat-radio-group>

<div>Your favorite season is: {{favoriteSeason}}</div>
<div>
  <button (click)="onSubmit()">Submit</button>
</div>
```

[Stackblitz demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/dencv1?file=src%2Fexample%2Fradio-ng-model-example.html)